# Parse array and push not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm starting with an array like this (from `console_log`) stored in a variable `cbsaList`:

```
[Object, Object, Object]
     0: Object
        cbsa name: "Dothan, AL"
     1: Object
        cbsa name: "Gadsden, AL"
     2: Object
        cbsa name: "Birmingham-Hoover, AL"
      length: 3
```

I'm trying to just get the 3 `cbsa name`s as a comma separated string.

I've tried this, but it's coming back as undefined:

```
 var all_cbsa =[];
 $.each(data, function(i, cbsaList) {
 all_cbsa.push(cbsaList['cbsa name']);
 console.log(all_cbsa); //undefined
  });
```

What am I messing up here?

Comment: Is the original array `data` ?

Comment: I suppose so... `var cbsas = data.names;`

Comment: Dumb mistake...changed this `$.each(data, function(i, cbsaList) {` to `$.each(cbsaList, function(i, cbsaList) {` and got it working thanks to you. Feel free to post as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Most likely it's an issue with your variable names, because your example works perfectly: http://jsfiddle.net/43yswzLz/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Synchronous version:

```
var data = [
    {
        cbsa_name:'test'
    },
    {
        cbsa_name:'test2'
    }
];

function buildListFromArrayByKey(arr, key) {
    var result = "";
    var len = arr.length - 1;

    for(var i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
        //if its the last index don't add a comma
        if(i == len) {
           result += arr[i][key];        
        }else{
           //add coma
           result += arr[i][key] + ',';
        }
    }

    return result;
}

var list = buildListFromArrayByKey(data,'cbsa_name');
```